# Trying to call a server side method from dynamic generated button control on client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i'm trying to call a server side method from dynamic generated button control on client side.but not able to call.Any idea would be appreciated.

.aspx

```
 var s = $(' <input type="button" ID="btnFrmSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  value="FrmSubmit" OnClick="Export_to_PDF" />');
                $("#btnExport").after(s);
```

c#

```
protected void Export_to_PDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
}
```

Comment: are you sure your jquery is working and button is adding to view?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain i have shown a pat of code only and my  jquery is working and button is adding to view.

Comment: Since you generated this in JS, it does not get bound to the server side method. That would only happen if you created it as an `<asp:Button` which was evaluated by the ASP.NET engine and turned into a HTML button, with the correct client & server scripts calculated in order to trigger the Export_to_PDF event. ASP has no way to know that you added a button using client-side code, because it's happening in a totally separate environment. I think what you should do is make a button using `<asp:Button`, but hide it. Then use JS to show it when you need it, instead of creating a new button.

Comment: As @ADyson said it cannot be done. Try some thing else, like convert your server side method to webmethod and use ajax to call it or don't add btnFrmSubmit button dynamically and play with it's visibility.

Comment: @ADyson k thx ..